# Installing compiler for C in Windows?

Tags: c, windows, mingw, clion, jetbrains-ide

I have installed a compiler, yet it consistently bottlenecks on "Detecting..." for about 30 seconds before refreshing and repeating the cycle. Can't find any solutions on google.

I'm currently running on Windows 10, followed various tutorials on YouTube and still stuck with this problem, I'm running on the latest version of CLion at the time of posting this question.

Am I doing something wrong? Here is an image of the "Toolchains" CLion window, unfortinatly I can't post the actual image as I don't have enough reputation right now.

[image: dialog window screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Add the 'bin' folder to the Path variable in windows [On Win 10, right-click on 'This PC' and select Properties -> Advanced system settings -> Environment variables... -> under 'System Variables' -> find 'Path' -> click 'Edit'] and added: c:\MinGW\bin

after try in CLion, if not run set manually :

- Environment: c:\MinGW\bin
- Make : mingw32-make.exe
- C compiler : mingw32-gcc.exe
- C++ compiler : mingw32-g++.exe